# How to Configure Build as Unstable vs Failed in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, gatling

in the Jenkins UI, how can I set whether a build should be considered unstable(yellow), or failure(red)?  This is for a Maven build, Gatling performance test.

Answer (score 0):

Use the text-finder plugin . https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=753775#content/view/753775 you can search for a status or a string in the build log and mark either failure or unstable

Comment: I did see this method, was looking for something UI based.  Edited my question since it was not specific enough.

Comment: You can also with newer versions of Jenkins use the built in variable Currentbuild and set it equal to unstable

Comment: Oh so u mean u want to Mark some build as unstable after the build has ran and i want to this from the ui?

Comment: In that case, I don’t think that is possible , I will take a look

Comment: Yes, based on pre-defined criteria.  I had a plugin installed that did this at another job, but can't remember what it was.  Basically if one test fails, mark it unstable.  If the job fails to build, mark it build failure.

Comment: I think this is actually a difference of working with Gatling vs the other integration frameworks I've used.  Assert failures in Gatling are automatically reported as build failures.  Have a question out to the Gatling team on this, will see what they say.